# Get data from MAP to subscribe?

Tags: angular, dictionary, subscribe

This feels like a stupid question and the answer i imagine would be simple and something im close to but cant quiet get yet, I use map to interact with a http request then subscribe to actually launch it; like so

```
  public update(idtoken: string, name: string, picture: string):any {
    var body = { idtoken : idtoken, type: 'update', name: name, picture: picture };
    return this.http.post(global.url + '/api/user', body, {}).map(result =>
    {
      console.log(result);
    });
  }
```

And to access/push this request in an actual component its used like this:

```
dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
            if(!isNullOrUndefined(result)) {
                if (!isNullOrUndefined(result.name)) {
                    this.name = result.name;
                }
                if (!isNullOrUndefined(result.image)) {
                    this.profileImage = result.image;
                }
                this.userService.update(this.id_token,this.name, this.profileImage).subscribe(result => console.log(result));
            }
        });
```

What I dont understand is how I can pass data from the map(x => {x...}) and then grab it with subscribe like subscribe(x => {popup(x.result)}) ('x' being the same value that was used/retrieved with the map function.

I wish to do this so I can properly read and react to an error and doing it within a service seems like the incorrect manner to do this. If this is not possible without some silly 'hack' method like passing the result to a service/global value etc and I just need to reformat my programming thats okay id rather get it right the first time.

Comment: just to get it right, you load something through your `update` function and want to map the results to something different, let's just call it `adjustedResult`. Then when you actually subscribe to that call, you want to use the `adjustedResult`. Or do you want to access the original object?

Comment: I want my subscribe function to be able to access the actual raw results (whether that be through the map function passing the result, or something similar)

Comment: If you never really want to alter your results in any way then `map` is not even necessary. This probably depends on wether your using HttpClient or Http service. Map is good to adjust your results before they are used, for example in the old Http service you had to manually parse your results to json,which is now done automatically. But if you always and only want your ain results, just remove `map`, then your code should be fine